# Publish Google Sheets Cell Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Has anyone written code to publish a range of cells in New Google Sheets to the web. The standard function of publishing allows you to only publish either the entire workbook or a single sheet, not specific ranges or for that matter any number of ranges.

Comment: Could probably have a script copy&paste the desired ranges to a new sheet that is published to the web.

Comment: or better than cut&paste, a sheet with a specific range lookup to the source sheet. use `QUERY`, `FILTER` or even just `=arrayformula(A1:D4)` in a single cell.